# ProFTPd configuration mod_auth_file cross folders with different rights in groups

Tags: ftp, configuration, proftpd

I have decided to use mod_auth_file, and made AuthGroupFile and AuthUserFile but each user points to own home directory /home/username as described in AuthUserFile.
How to get server to work in structure as described below ?

```
Group 'developers':
   /upload      read/write
   /source      read/write
   /project1    read/write
   /project2    read/write

Group 'project1':
   /upload      read/write
   /project1    read

Group 'project2':
   /upload      read/write
   /project2    read
```

these folders supposed to be shared across all users.
all folders physically lay out in single root folder for example /srv/ftp

Answer (score 0):

The directives [**DefaultChdir**](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultChdir.html) and [**DefaultRoot**](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DefaultRoot.html) support this kind of behaviour.

Comment: can you provide more info, maybe config example suitable for my needs ?

Comment: sorry, but still can't fugure out how configure it, any additional info will be helpfull